# Slider circulation without hidden elements

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

At the current moment I don't know how to fix this problem (see code and example). First should go left, after click left, from right side should be first element and on complete remove from DOM first element, which invisible. All this should be animated.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="arrow-left left" href="#">&lt;</a>
    <div class=slider>
        <ul>
            <li class="red"></li>
            <li class="black"></li>
            <li class="yellow"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a  class="arrow-right right"  href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

My jQuery plugin

```
(function($) {

    var options = {
        leftBtn: '.arrow-left',
        rightBtn: '.arrow-right',
        animationSpeed: 5,
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            var option = $.extend({
                leftBtn: '.arrow-left',
                rightBtn: '.arrow-right',
                animationSpeed: 5
            }, options);
            var $leftArrow = $(option.leftBtn);
            var $rightArrow = $(option.leftBtn);
            $( '.arrow-left' ).bind( 'click', methods.left );
            $( '.arrow-right').bind( 'click', methods.right );
        },
        left : function() {
            var $self = $('.arrow-left');
            var $parent = $self.closest('.wrapper');
            var $ul = $parent.find('ul');
            var $first = $ul.find('li').first();
            $first.clone().appendTo($ul);
            $ul.find('li').animate({left: "-=100"}, 800, function() {
                //$first.remove();
            });

            //$first.remove();
        },
        right : function() {
            var $self = $('.arrow-right');
            var $parent = $self.closest('.wrapper');
            var $ul = $parent.find('ul');
            var $first = $ul.find('li').last();
            $first.clone().prependTo($ul);
            $first.remove();
        },
        destroy : function() {
            $( '.left' ).unbind( 'click', methods.left );
            $( '.right').unbind( 'click', methods.right );
        }
    };

    $.fn.mySlider = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error(method + ' doesn\'t exist for plugin jQuery.mySlider' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );

$('.wrapper').mySlider();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GmanG/hb9m42rc/1/

Also how correct extend default options and create callback function?

Thank you.